# Permission denied when using Python request session to make multiple requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I am trying to automate 2 requests using python, first request is `GET` and the 2nd is `POST`

Here is how I manually do it using Chrome,

I visit `http://testserver/index` on chrome browser. 
It prompt me for `NTLM` login. I provided username/password which was successful. Then I went on another page,
`http://testserver/find_user` and enter a `username` to search for. I press entered which displayed the results.

Then I copy the `curl` request from Chrome, convert it into python code and got this,

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth("DOSTR\\TESTUSER", getpass.getpass('Password:'))

    url = "http://testserver/find_user"

    payload = "username=test"

    headers = {
        'Connection': "keep-alive",
        'Cache-Control': "max-age=0",
        'Origin': "http://testserver",
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1",
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        'Referer': "http://testserver/find_user?thread=2&aftk-687=-719740030",
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
        'Accept-Language': "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        'Cookie': "JSESSIONID=4D8270489027BCD04777AAB32769B3A9; lang=en; mode=index"
        }

    response = session.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)
```

The above request works.

But the problem is I have to make a first request using Chrome to generate cookies.

So I tried making the first request using Python as well like this, and use its cookies in the 2nd request

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth("DOSTR\\TESTUSER", getpass.getpass('Password:'))
    url = "http://testserver/index" 
    headers = {
        'Connection': "keep-alive",
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1",
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
        'Accept-Language': "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
        }

    response = session.request("GET", url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

    # now 2nd request in same session with cookies of above response.

    url = "http://testserver/find_user"

    payload = "username=test"

    headers = {
        'Connection': "keep-alive",
        'Cache-Control': "max-age=0",
        'Origin': "http://testserver",
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1",
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        'Referer': "http://testserver/find_user?thread=2&aftk-687=-719740030",
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
        'Accept-Language': "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
        }

    response = session.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, cookies=response.cookies)

    print(response.text)
```

But I keep getting permission denied error on the 2nd request (The `GET` request is successful, and I can see the output if I print it)

it only works when I use the cookies in 2nd request generated by Chrome, but not when I generate those cookies using python

I am not sure why the cookies from first request is not working in the 2nd request.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Response header from `GET` request in chrome,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F8DC91356195C0D1730638B81A60F6EB; Path=/index/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: lang=en; Expires=Mon, 09-Apr-2068 18:49:54 GMT
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2019 21:24:57 GMT
Content-Length: 13267
```

Response header from `GET` request in Python,

```
{'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '984', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Expires': 'Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=EF3589A5EC319542C6254C16418F6265; Path=/index/; HttpOnly', 'Persistent-Auth': 'true', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Tue, 05 Feb 2019 21:27:33 GMT'}
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be session.request instead of request.request on the second one as well?

Comment: @SimonF sorry i used `session.request` indeed(modified the code)

Comment: Have you looked at the cookies to see whats different?

Comment: @SimonF I have added the `headers` from both chrome and python